# Filling a two dimensional array of structs with information from a one dimensional array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I wrote a function that successfully reads a CSV file with the following format for each record:

```
name_of_class,name_of_class_member,double_associated_with_class,double_associated_with_class_member,another_double_associated_with_class_member
```

My function reads the CSV file and creates a one-dimensional array of structs, where each record corresponds to an element in the one-dimensional array of structs.

My question is this: how can I copy the information for each record into a two-dimensional array of structures, with the indices `data[class][member_of_class]` instead of `data[record]`?

It's tricky, because different classes have different numbers of members. I initialized a 2-dimensional array with the dimensions `classes * max_num_members` and set the values of the 2D array to zero (or, in the case of char arrays, I used spaces that would later be written over by other characters). So, obviously, there will be many values (equal to zero for doubles or white space for char arrays) in the 2D array that have not been changed by copying from the 1D array. I can skip these in my main algorithm using a sentinel.

The goal is to use my nested for loops later in the code to loop over members of the class as the nested loop and loop over classes as the outer loop. That part of the code is finished and working correctly, but I need the data to be read into the array of structs that the algorithm uses. Anyone know how to do this?

The alternative is to read my records from the csv file into a 2D array, but that really just transfers from the problem from one location to another. Class names have no more than ten characters and member names have no more than thirteen characters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct csv
{
    char class_name[12];
    char member[18];
    double class_value;
    double member_value1;
    double member_value2;
    double calc_output1;  // Program I'm writing adds values here
    double calc_output2; // And here
};

void readFile(char *csvFile, struct csv *csv_rec)
{
    /* code for reading file here - this works as planned.
       Reads csv file and makes 1D array of structs with num_records
       elements */
    FILE *dataFile = NULL;
//  size_t idx_i = 0;       // struct array index i (increments after every record -> resets to zero when a new ligand is found)
//  size_t idx_j = 0;       // struct array index j (only increments when a new ligand is found)
    size_t idx = 0;         // okay - this lie_read struct array will be one-dimensional - one index per record
    size_t fldidx = 0;      // struct field index
    char fileLine[255] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;         // pointer to line

    dataFile = fopen(myFile, "r");

    // Open the file set by the command line and read it into the file object
    dataFile = fopen(myFile, "r");
    if (dataFile == NULL){
        perror("Error opening data file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // Exit program if data file cannot be read by runtime service
    }

    while ((fgets (fileLine, 254, dataFile)) != NULL){
        fldidx = 0;     // reset field index for each line
        // Use strtok to separate each line into tokens on ','
        for (p = strtok(fileLine, ","); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ",")){
            // Use fldidx to separate data into struct
            switch (fldidx){

                case 0:
                    strncpy(lie_rec[idx].class_name, p, strlen(p));
                    break;

                case 1:
                    strncpy(lie_rec[idx].member, p, strlen(p));
                    break;

                case 2:
                    lie_rec[idx].class_value = atof(p);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    lie_rec[idx].member_value1 = atof(p);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    lie_rec[idx].member_value2 = atof(p);
                    break;
            }
            // Increment field index
            fldidx++;
        }
        // Increment record index
        idx++;
    }
    // Close dataFile object
    fclose(dataFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num_records = 75; // Later a function will count these
    struct csv csv_data[m_members][n_classes]; // Declare 2D array 
    struct csv csv_read[num_records]; // 1D array of structs
    int i; // index for printing out 2D array
    int j; // index for printing out 2D array
    int members; // members counter for algorithm I wrote
    int classes; // classes counter
    int records; // index of records
    int m_members = 25; // Bigger than it needs to be for any file
    int n_classes = 25; // Bigger than needs to be for any file

    // Initialize csv_data 2D array:
    for (i = 0; i < m; i += 1){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j += 1){
            strcpy(csv_data[i][j].class_name, "          ");
            strcpy(csv_data[i][j].member, "                ");
            csv_data[i][j].class_value = 0.0;
            csv_data[i][j].member_value1 = 0.0;
            csv_data[i][j].member_value2 = 0.0;
            csv_data[i][j].calc_output1 = 0.0;
            csv_data[i][j].calc_output2 = 0.0;
        }
   }
// Initialize csv_read struct array
    for (records = 0; records < num_records; records += 1){
        strcpy(csv_read[records].class_name, "          ");
        strcpy(csv_read[records].member, "                ");
        csv_read[records].class_value = 0.0;
        csv_read[records].member_value1 = 0.0;
        csv_read[records].member_value2 = 0.0;
        csv_read[records].calc_output1 = 0.0;
        csv_read[records].calc_output2 = 0.0;
    }

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: ./optimization datafile.csv\n");
        return 1;       
    }

    readFile (argv[1], csv_read);

    // Here is what I have so far. It doesn't work:
    // First, set member and class indices to zero
    members = 0;
    classes = 0;

   // Next, copy values held in first record to 0,0 index of 2D array
       strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].class_name, csv_read[0].class_name);
       strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].member, csv_read[0].member);
       csv_data[classes][members].class_value = csv_read[0].class_value;
       csv_data[classes][members].member_value1 = csv_read[0].member_value1;
       csv_data[classes][members].member_value2 = csv_read[0].member_value2;

       // This is the part I'm not doing correctly:
      for (records = 1; records < num_records; records += 1){
          if (csv_read[records].class_name == csv_read[records -1].class_name){
              members += 1;
              strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].class_name, csv_read[records].class_name);
              strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].member, csv_read[records].member);
              csv_data[classes][members].class_value = csv_read[records].class_value;
              csv_data[classes][members].member_value1 = csv_read[records].member_value1;
              csv_data[classes][members].member_value2 = csv_read[records].member_value2;
          }
          else{
              members = 0;
              classes += 1;
              strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].class_name, csv_read[records].class_name);
              strcpy(csv_data[classes][members].member, csv_read[records].member);
              csv_data[classes][members].class_value = csv_read[records].class_value;
              csv_data[classes][members].member_value1 = csv_read[records].member_value1;
              csv_data[classes][members].member_value2 = csv_read[records].member_value2;
          }
      }
  for (i = 0; i < n_classes; i += 1){
      for (j = 0; j < m_members; j += 1){
            printf("Class: %s\tMember: %s\tClass val: %.2f\tMem val 1: %.2f\tMem val 2: %.2f\tClass index i: %d\tMember index j: %d\n", \
            csv_data[i][j].class_name, csv_data[i][j].member, csv_data[i][j].class_value, \
            csv_data[i][j].member_value1, csv_data[i][j].member_value2, i, j);

            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Consider the following data:

```
RTI-31,nma-10-325,-9.189617432,-1.695719104,-17.76402898
RTI-31,nma-04-176,-9.189617432,-0.708200772,-17.29511154
RTI-31,nma-04-176r,-9.189617432,-1.776907169,-18.88678457
RTI-31,md2-02-280,-9.189617432,-6.716602886,-17.30751521
RTI-31,nma-10-346,-9.189617432,-11.25116643,-15.84743342
RTI-31,nma-04-263,-9.189617432,-11.7115346,-15.04227866
RTI-31,nma-08-195,-9.189617432,-4.283013542,-14.8644087
RTI-31,nma-04-009,-9.189617432,-9.957288662,-15.3833286
RTI-32,nma-10-088,-8.122152987,3.400737344,-13.82064615
RTI-32,nma-04-394,-8.122152987,5.883495783,-19.00254755
RTI-32,nma-08-230,-8.122152987,0.413386417,-17.50831526
RTI-32,md2-01-186,-8.122152987,2.302141507,-18.42063173
RTI-32,md2-02-029,-8.122152987,-0.853363293,-19.87712031
RTI-32,md2-03-113,-8.122152987,-2.126838817,-17.89035308
RTI-32,md2-03-408,-8.122152987,-2.378811839,-19.10012534
RTI-32,nma-08-230r,-8.122152987,-3.518076683,-15.81202945
RTI-32,md2-02-440,-8.122152987,-1.188031285,-19.53715485
RTI-32,nma-10-450,-8.122152987,-8.146774789,-16.31970845
RTI-55,nma-10-001,-10.81805764,-5.533121698,-21.43344143
RTI-55,mod-15-206,-10.81805764,-7.885292487,-15.77724091
RTI-55,mod-15-315,-10.81805764,-8.856570799,-14.75351417
RTI-55,md2-02-326,-10.81805764,-5.707098223,-17.26686476
RTI-55,md2-02-385-2ns,-10.81805764,-4.121861538,-19.3591163
RTI-55,md2-02-385,-10.81805764,-4.947616016,-18.97695889
RTI-55,mod-20-399,-10.81805764,-10.22068836,-16.32632494
RTI-55,nma-04-221,-10.81805764,-10.71500752,-16.91671567
RTI-55,nma-10-386,-10.81805764,-1.85786946,-16.19619261
RTI-83,nma-10-442,-8.776665815,-2.051376338,-15.3196037
RTI-83,nma-07-088,-8.776665815,-0.539301859,-15.72769426
RTI-83,md2-02-373,-8.776665815,-1.906149626,-16.11155781
RTI-83,nma-08-131,-8.776665815,0.313343619,-19.40078361
RTI-83,nma-08-496,-8.776665815,1.261873671,-19.855084
RTI-83,nma-08-496r,-8.776665815,-3.209539767,-19.77852301
RTI-83,nma-10-083,-8.776665815,-1.389051189,-16.46193737
RTI-112,nma-04-356,-10.01552067,-7.703118545,-18.74684866
RTI-112,nma-12-269,-10.01552067,-2.041048837,-17.43378148
RTI-112,md2-02-251,-10.01552067,-4.164610755,-18.10792907
RTI-112,md2-03-020,-10.01552067,-5.530673965,-18.65868875
RTI-112,md2-03-112,-10.01552067,-4.616037982,-17.8977875
RTI-112,md2-05-001r,-10.01552067,10.61243604,-18.16726877
RTI-112,md2-02-424,-10.01552067,-6.748664848,-14.45256624
RTI-112,md2-04-136,-10.01552067,-1.418702078,-17.52802883
RTI-112,md2-04-432,-10.01552067,5.711770139,-19.62800474
RTI-112,nma-12-269r,-10.01552067,6.293115989,-21.18562611
RTI-112,md2-02-366,-10.01552067,-7.398526621,-15.27947209
RTI-112,nma-10-060,-10.01552067,0.203776856,-16.07514793
RTI-112,nma-10-009,-10.01552067,-8.496101809,-15.4687674
RTI-121,nma-04-080,-8.23077347,-13.26577889,-19.92387515
RTI-121,md2-02-121,-8.23077347,-6.908416206,-21.19849859
RTI-121,md2-01-352,-8.23077347,-3.905511834,-20.05735835
RTI-121,md2-02-008,-8.23077347,-7.466873501,-20.41795091
RTI-121,md2-03-176,-8.23077347,-10.52147618,-20.31241965
RTI-121,md2-03-414,-8.23077347,-8.16490714,-21.51488985
RTI-121,md2-02-161,-8.23077347,-10.90084,-18.37585263
RTI-121,md2-02-385,-8.23077347,0.522082608,-16.89841543
RTI-121,nma-09-401,-8.23077347,-9.558324522,-18.10430351
RTI-121,nma-10-395,-8.23077347,-2.742911754,-17.7883527
RTI-311,nma-10-120,-9.189617432,-13.42937635,-14.86997145
RTI-311,md2-02-009,-9.189617432,-6.894222241,-15.63990294
RTI-311,mod-22-300,-9.189617432,-12.76870958,-16.02814399
CPT,mod-08-107,-7.817821853,4.236459518,-19.75666039
CPT,md2-02-359,-7.817821853,-3.738716789,-16.07115237
CPT,mod-22-290,-7.817821853,6.6227657,-16.84444512
CPT,nma-10-155,-7.817821853,-1.792262141,-13.302963
CPT,nma-10-405,-7.817821853,-2.6011009,-15.99324198
CFT,mod-08-220,-8.451839575,-3.405297094,-18.91334067
CFT,md2-02-111,-8.451839575,-6.573973681,-14.8400486
```

Produces these strange results (notice the last class - CFT -has not been printed):

```
]]RTI-31,nma-10-325,-9.189617432,-1.695719104,-17.76402898
]]RTI-31,nma-04-176,-9.189617432,-0.708200772,-17.29511154
]]RTI-31,nma-04-176r,-9.189617432,-1.776907169,-18.88678457
]]RTI-31,md2-02-280,-9.189617432,-6.716602886,-17.30751521
]]RTI-31,nma-10-346,-9.189617432,-11.25116643,-15.84743342
]]RTI-31,nma-04-263,-9.189617432,-11.7115346,-15.04227866
]]RTI-31,nma-08-195,-9.189617432,-4.283013542,-14.8644087
]]RTI-31,nma-04-009,-9.189617432,-9.957288662,-15.3833286
]]RTI-32,nma-10-088,-8.122152987,3.400737344,-13.82064615
]]RTI-32,nma-04-394,-8.122152987,5.883495783,-19.00254755
]]RTI-32,nma-08-230,-8.122152987,0.413386417,-17.50831526
]]RTI-32,md2-01-186,-8.122152987,2.302141507,-18.42063173
]]RTI-32,md2-02-029,-8.122152987,-0.853363293,-19.87712031
]]RTI-32,md2-03-113,-8.122152987,-2.126838817,-17.89035308
]]RTI-32,md2-03-408,-8.122152987,-2.378811839,-19.10012534
]]RTI-32,nma-08-230r,-8.122152987,-3.518076683,-15.81202945
]]RTI-32,md2-02-440,-8.122152987,-1.188031285,-19.53715485
]]RTI-32,nma-10-450,-8.122152987,-8.146774789,-16.31970845
]]RTI-55,nma-10-001,-10.81805764,-5.533121698,-21.43344143
]]RTI-55,mod-15-206,-10.81805764,-7.885292487,-15.77724091
]]RTI-55,mod-15-315,-10.81805764,-8.856570799,-14.75351417
]]RTI-55,md2-02-326,-10.81805764,-5.707098223,-17.26686476
]]RTI-55,md2-02-385-2ns,-10.81805764,-4.121861538,-19.3591163
]]RTI-55,md2-02-385,-10.81805764,-4.947616016,-18.97695889
]]RTI-55,mod-20-399,-10.81805764,-10.22068836,-16.32632494
]]RTI-55,nma-04-221,-10.81805764,-10.71500752,-16.91671567
]]RTI-55,nma-10-386,-10.81805764,-1.85786946,-16.19619261
]]RTI-83,nma-10-442,-8.776665815,-2.051376338,-15.3196037
]]RTI-83,nma-07-088,-8.776665815,-0.539301859,-15.72769426
]]RTI-83,md2-02-373,-8.776665815,-1.906149626,-16.11155781
]]RTI-83,nma-08-131,-8.776665815,0.313343619,-19.40078361
]]RTI-83,nma-08-496,-8.776665815,1.261873671,-19.855084
]]RTI-83,nma-08-496r,-8.776665815,-3.209539767,-19.77852301
]]RTI-83,nma-10-083,-8.776665815,-1.389051189,-16.46193737
]]RTI-112,nma-04-356,-10.01552067,-7.703118545,-18.74684866
]]RTI-112,nma-12-269,-10.01552067,-2.041048837,-17.43378148
]]RTI-112,md2-02-251,-10.01552067,-4.164610755,-18.10792907
]]RTI-112,md2-03-020,-10.01552067,-5.530673965,-18.65868875
]]RTI-112,md2-03-112,-10.01552067,-4.616037982,-17.8977875
]]RTI-112,md2-05-001r,-10.01552067,10.61243604,-18.16726877
]]RTI-112,md2-02-424,-10.01552067,-6.748664848,-14.45256624
]]RTI-112,md2-04-136,-10.01552067,-1.418702078,-17.52802883
]]RTI-112,md2-04-432,-10.01552067,5.711770139,-19.62800474
]]RTI-112,nma-12-269r,-10.01552067,6.293115989,-21.18562611
]]RTI-112,md2-02-366,-10.01552067,-7.398526621,-15.27947209
]]RTI-112,nma-10-060,-10.01552067,0.203776856,-16.07514793
]]RTI-112,nma-10-009,-10.01552067,-8.496101809,-15.4687674
]]RTI-121,nma-04-080,-8.23077347,-13.26577889,-19.92387515
]]RTI-121,md2-02-121,-8.23077347,-6.908416206,-21.19849859
]]RTI-121,md2-01-352,-8.23077347,-3.905511834,-20.05735835
]]RTI-121,md2-02-008,-8.23077347,-7.466873501,-20.41795091
]]RTI-121,md2-03-176,-8.23077347,-10.52147618,-20.31241965
]]RTI-121,md2-03-414,-8.23077347,-8.16490714,-21.51488985
]]RTI-121,md2-02-161,-8.23077347,-10.90084,-18.37585263
]]RTI-121,md2-02-385,-8.23077347,0.522082608,-16.89841543
]]RTI-121,nma-09-401,-8.23077347,-9.558324522,-18.10430351
]]RTI-121,nma-10-395,-8.23077347,-2.742911754,-17.7883527
]]RTI-311,nma-10-120,-9.189617432,-13.42937635,-14.86997145
]]RTI-311,md2-02-009,-9.189617432,-6.894222241,-15.63990294
]]RTI-311,mod-22-300,-9.189617432,-12.76870958,-16.02814399
]]CPT,mod-08-107,-7.817821853,4.236459518,-19.75666039
]]CPT,md2-02-359,-7.817821853,-3.738716789,-16.07115237
]]CPT,mod-22-290,-7.817821853,6.6227657,-16.84444512
]]CPT,nma-10-155,-7.817821853,-1.792262141,-13.302963
]]CPT,nma-10-405,-7.817821853,-2.6011009,-15.99324198
]]CFT,mod-08-220,-8.451839575,-3.405297094,-18.91334067
]]CFT,md2-02-111,-8.451839575,-6.573973681,-14.8400486
[0,1] - A
[0,2] - A
[0,3] - A
[0,4] - A
[0,5] - A
[0,6] - A
[0,7] - A
[1,0] - B
[1,1] - A
[1,2] - A
[1,3] - A
[1,4] - A
[1,5] - A
[1,6] - A
[1,7] - A
[1,8] - A
[1,9] - A
[2,0] - B
[2,1] - A
[2,2] - A
[2,3] - A
[2,4] - A
[2,5] - A
[2,6] - A
[2,7] - A
[2,8] - A
[3,0] - B
[3,1] - A
[3,2] - A
[3,3] - A
[3,4] - A
[3,5] - A
[3,6] - A
[4,0] - B
[4,1] - A
[4,2] - A
[4,3] - A
[4,4] - A
[4,5] - A
[4,6] - A
[4,7] - A
[4,8] - A
[4,9] - A
[4,10] - A
[4,11] - A
[4,12] - A
[5,0] - B
[5,1] - A
[5,2] - A
[5,3] - A
[5,4] - A
[5,5] - A
[5,6] - A
[5,7] - A
[5,8] - A
[5,9] - A
[6,0] - B
[6,1] - A
[6,2] - A
[7,0] - B
[7,1] - A
[7,2] - A
[7,3] - A
[7,4] - A
[8,0] - B
[8,1] - A
Class         Member                C-Value  M-Value 1  M-Value 2   Class  Member
RTI-31        nma-10-325              -9.19      -1.70     -17.76       0       0
RTI-31        nma-04-176              -9.19      -0.71     -17.30       0       1
RTI-31        nma-04-176r             -9.19      -1.78     -18.89       0       2
RTI-31        md2-02-280              -9.19      -6.72     -17.31       0       3
RTI-31        nma-10-346              -9.19     -11.25     -15.85       0       4
RTI-31        nma-04-263              -9.19     -11.71     -15.04       0       5
RTI-31        nma-08-195              -9.19      -4.28     -14.86       0       6
RTI-31        nma-04-009              -9.19      -9.96     -15.38       0       7
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0       8
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0      11
RTI-32        nma-10-088              -8.12       3.40     -13.82       1       0
RTI-32        nma-04-394              -8.12       5.88     -19.00       1       1
RTI-32        nma-08-230              -8.12       0.41     -17.51       1       2
RTI-32        md2-01-186              -8.12       2.30     -18.42       1       3
RTI-32        md2-02-029              -8.12      -0.85     -19.88       1       4
RTI-32        md2-03-113              -8.12      -2.13     -17.89       1       5
RTI-32        md2-03-408              -8.12      -2.38     -19.10       1       6
RTI-32        nma-08-230r             -8.12      -3.52     -15.81       1       7
RTI-32        md2-02-440              -8.12      -1.19     -19.54       1       8
RTI-32        nma-10-450              -8.12      -8.15     -16.32       1       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       1      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       1      11
RTI-55        nma-10-001             -10.82      -5.53     -21.43       2       0
RTI-55        mod-15-206             -10.82      -7.89     -15.78       2       1
RTI-55        mod-15-315             -10.82      -8.86     -14.75       2       2
RTI-55        md2-02-326             -10.82      -5.71     -17.27       2       3
RTI-55        md2-02-385-2ns         -10.82      -4.12     -19.36       2       4
RTI-55        md2-02-385             -10.82      -4.95     -18.98       2       5
RTI-55        mod-20-399             -10.82     -10.22     -16.33       2       6
RTI-55        nma-04-221             -10.82     -10.72     -16.92       2       7
RTI-55        nma-10-386             -10.82      -1.86     -16.20       2       8
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       2       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       2      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       2      11
RTI-83        nma-10-442              -8.78      -2.05     -15.32       3       0
RTI-83        nma-07-088              -8.78      -0.54     -15.73       3       1
RTI-83        md2-02-373              -8.78      -1.91     -16.11       3       2
RTI-83        nma-08-131              -8.78       0.31     -19.40       3       3
RTI-83        nma-08-496              -8.78       1.26     -19.86       3       4
RTI-83        nma-08-496r             -8.78      -3.21     -19.78       3       5
RTI-83        nma-10-083              -8.78      -1.39     -16.46       3       6
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3       7
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3       8
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3      11
RTI-112       nma-04-356             -10.02      -7.70     -18.75       4       0
RTI-112       nma-12-269             -10.02      -2.04     -17.43       4       1
RTI-112       md2-02-251             -10.02      -4.16     -18.11       4       2
RTI-112       md2-03-020             -10.02      -5.53     -18.66       4       3
RTI-112       md2-03-112             -10.02      -4.62     -17.90       4       4
RTI-112       md2-05-001r            -10.02      10.61     -18.17       4       5
RTI-112       md2-02-424             -10.02      -6.75     -14.45       4       6
RTI-112       md2-04-136             -10.02      -1.42     -17.53       4       7
RTI-112       md2-04-432             -10.02       5.71     -19.63       4       8
RTI-112       nma-12-269r            -10.02       6.29     -21.19       4       9
RTI-112       md2-02-366             -10.02      -7.40     -15.28       4      10
RTI-112       nma-10-060             -10.02       0.20     -16.08       4      11
RTI-121       nma-04-080              -8.23     -13.27     -19.92       5       0
RTI-121       md2-02-121              -8.23      -6.91     -21.20       5       1
RTI-121       md2-01-352              -8.23      -3.91     -20.06       5       2
RTI-121       md2-02-008              -8.23      -7.47     -20.42       5       3
RTI-121       md2-03-176              -8.23     -10.52     -20.31       5       4
RTI-121       md2-03-414              -8.23      -8.16     -21.51       5       5
RTI-121       md2-02-161              -8.23     -10.90     -18.38       5       6
RTI-121       md2-02-385              -8.23       0.52     -16.90       5       7
RTI-121       nma-09-401              -8.23      -9.56     -18.10       5       8
RTI-121       nma-10-395              -8.23      -2.74     -17.79       5       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5      11
RTI-311       nma-10-120              -9.19     -13.43     -14.87       6       0
RTI-311       md2-02-009              -9.19      -6.89     -15.64       6       1
RTI-311       mod-22-300              -9.19     -12.77     -16.03       6       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       4
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       5
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       6
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       7
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       8
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6      11
CPT           mod-08-107              -7.82       4.24     -19.76       7       0
CPT           md2-02-359              -7.82      -3.74     -16.07       7       1
CPT           mod-22-290              -7.82       6.62     -16.84       7       2
CPT           nma-10-155              -7.82      -1.79     -13.30       7       3
CPT           nma-10-405              -7.82      -2.60     -15.99       7       4
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       5
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       6
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       7
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       8
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       9
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7      10
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7      11
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Is it the data file format?

Comment: How do you know how many records were read by `readFile()`?  You have no way to tell it how much space it can use, nor can it tell you how much space it used.  You have a design problem there.

Comment: You should read up on structure assignment.  It would radically simplify the code.  Also, string comparison requires `strcmp()`; this code `if (csv_read[records].class_name == csv_read[records -1].class_name){` is comparing two pointers which are guaranteed to be unequal, even if the strings that they contain are equal.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I was going to write a function that reads the number of records in the input file. For now, I just want it to work for a single file I have, and I know how many records there are. There will never be a need for this script to read more than 100 records.

Comment: Thank you for that tip - this could explain my problem. This is the first C code I've ever written. Definitely still learning.

Comment: Generally, it will be better — simpler, easier to understand, more performant because the file is only read once (which really matters with big files, though not so much with 100-row files) — if you tell the input function how much space it has in the array, and it returns the number of entries it filled (0 or -1 can indicate errors, possibly different errors).  Don't assume that you'll never have a file that's too big — nor that you'll be able to open every file specified on the command line, nor that the files specified will always be in the correct format.

Comment: I will edit the code shown above to show my readFile function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some mildly fixed code.  There were problems with `myFile` vs `csvFile` and `lie_rec` vs `csv_rec` in the `readFile()` function.

Otherwise, I simplified record initialization with `empty` and structure assignment; I used simpler/different loop indexes in places; and added some diagnostic printing.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct csv
{
    char class_name[12];
    char member[18];
    double class_value;
    double member_value1;
    double member_value2;
    double calc_output1;  // Program I'm writing adds values here
    double calc_output2; // And here
};

static
int readFile(char *csvFile, struct csv *csv_rec, size_t max_records)
{
    /* code for reading file here - this works as planned.
       Reads csv file and makes 1D array of structs with up to max_records
       elements */
    FILE *dataFile = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t fldidx = 0;      // struct field index
    char fileLine[255] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;         // pointer to line

    // dataFile = fopen(csvFile, "r"); // Rename myFile -> csvFile; delete duplicate

    // Open the file set by the command line and read it into the file object
    dataFile = fopen(csvFile, "r");
    if (dataFile == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening data file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // Exit program if data file cannot be read by runtime service
    }

    while ((fgets(fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), dataFile)) != NULL)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(fileLine);
        if (len == 0)
            continue;
        fileLine[len - 1] = '\0';
        if (idx >= max_records)
            break;
        printf("[[%s]]\n", fileLine);
        fldidx = 0;     // reset field index for each line
        // Use strtok to separate each line into tokens on ','
        for (p = strtok(fileLine, ","); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, ","))
        {
            // Use fldidx to separate data into struct
            switch (fldidx)
            {
            case 0:
                // JL: lie_rec --> csv_rec
                strncpy(csv_rec[idx].class_name, p, strlen(p));
                break;
            case 1:
                strncpy(csv_rec[idx].member, p, strlen(p));
                break;
            case 2:
                csv_rec[idx].class_value = atof(p);
                break;
            case 3:
                csv_rec[idx].member_value1 = atof(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                csv_rec[idx].member_value2 = atof(p);
                break;
            }
            // Increment field index
            fldidx++;
        }
        // Increment record index
        idx++;
    }
    // Close dataFile object
    fclose(dataFile);
    return idx;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int m_members = 25; // Bigger than it needs to be for any file
    int n_classes = 25; // Bigger than needs to be for any file
    int n_records = 75; // Later a function will count these
    struct csv csv_data[m_members][n_classes]; // Declare 2D array
    struct csv csv_read[n_records]; // 1D array of structs
    struct csv empty = { "           ", "                 ", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

    // Initialize csv_data 2D array:
    for (int i = 0; i < m_members; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_classes; j++)
            csv_data[i][j] = empty;
    }

    // Initialize csv_read struct array
    for (int i = 0; i < n_records; i++)
        csv_read[i] = empty;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./optimization datafile.csv\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n_recs = readFile(argv[1], csv_read, n_records);

    // Here is what I have so far. It doesn't work:
    // First, set member and class indices to zero
    int members = 0;
    int classes = 0;
    int max_members = 0;

    // Next, copy values held in first record to 0,0 index of 2D array
    csv_data[classes][members] = csv_read[0];

    // This is the part I'm not doing correctly:
    for (int i = 1; i < n_recs; i++)
    {
        assert(members < m_members && classes < n_classes);
        if (strcmp(csv_read[i].class_name, csv_read[i - 1].class_name) == 0)
        {
            members += 1;
            csv_data[classes][members] = csv_read[i];
            printf("[%d,%d] - A\n", classes, members);
        }
        else
        {
            if (members > max_members)
                max_members = members;
            members = 0;
            classes += 1;
            csv_data[classes][members] = csv_read[i];
            printf("[%d,%d] - B\n", classes, members);
        }
    }

    printf("%-12s  %-18s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %6s  %6s\n",
           "Class", "Member", "C-Value", "M-Value 1", "M-Value 2", "Class", "Member");
    for (int i = 0; i < classes; i += 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < max_members; j += 1)
        {
            printf("%-12s  %-18s  %9.2f  %9.2f  %9.2f  %6d  %6d\n",
                   csv_data[i][j].class_name, csv_data[i][j].member,
                   csv_data[i][j].class_value, csv_data[i][j].member_value1,
                   csv_data[i][j].member_value2, i, j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For this data file (partially randomly generated, partially systematically edited):

```
Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,20.07,985.12,8816.17
Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,40.07,385.12,5816.17
Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,60.07,485.12,2816.17
Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,61.79,385.93,2477.32
Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,41.79,385.93,2477.32
Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,91.79,385.93,2477.32
Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,21.79,385.93,2477.32
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,66.53,103.14,6106.43
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,56.53,103.14,7106.43
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,46.53,103.14,8106.43
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,36.53,103.14,9106.43
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,26.53,103.14,1106.43
Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,16.53,103.14,2106.43
Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,36.89,435.08,5337.35
Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,56.89,435.08,5337.35
Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,76.89,435.08,5337.35
Zagahwfn,Hanhmrcdgryn,84.58,598.20,8854.05
Keivsvmcb,Maaqjraizoaz,36.60,316.95,4320.89
Hoawiopqby,Puqezsvrscs,44.77,131.01,4315.89
Zifummkfm,Uitgzpnziz,94.29,342.45,2152.53
Fikwzidv,Iamjbgihhrb,59.63,915.11,9885.05
Yutihgddt,Augpvalibavo,44.64,472.51,3092.39
```

I get the following diagnostic output:

```
[[Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,20.07,985.12,8816.17]]
[[Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,40.07,385.12,5816.17]]
[[Eeikehkt,Juxeizdiybnc,60.07,485.12,2816.17]]
[[Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,61.79,385.93,2477.32]]
[[Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,41.79,385.93,2477.32]]
[[Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,91.79,385.93,2477.32]]
[[Iamtppjo,Duxacewxhh,21.79,385.93,2477.32]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,66.53,103.14,6106.43]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,56.53,103.14,7106.43]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,46.53,103.14,8106.43]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,36.53,103.14,9106.43]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,26.53,103.14,1106.43]]
[[Harbegghs,Javqaqetlmf,16.53,103.14,2106.43]]
[[Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,36.89,435.08,5337.35]]
[[Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,56.89,435.08,5337.35]]
[[Zumnyqmiq,Luoyjcvvdtwh,76.89,435.08,5337.35]]
[[Zagahwfn,Hanhmrcdgryn,84.58,598.20,8854.05]]
[[Keivsvmcb,Maaqjraizoaz,36.60,316.95,4320.89]]
[[Hoawiopqby,Puqezsvrscs,44.77,131.01,4315.89]]
[[Zifummkfm,Uitgzpnziz,94.29,342.45,2152.53]]
[[Fikwzidv,Iamjbgihhrb,59.63,915.11,9885.05]]
[[Yutihgddt,Augpvalibavo,44.64,472.51,3092.39]]
[0,1] - A
[0,2] - A
[1,0] - B
[1,1] - A
[1,2] - A
[1,3] - A
[2,0] - B
[2,1] - A
[2,2] - A
[2,3] - A
[2,4] - A
[2,5] - A
[3,0] - B
[3,1] - A
[3,2] - A
[4,0] - B
[5,0] - B
[6,0] - B
[7,0] - B
[8,0] - B
[9,0] - B
```

followed by the following main output:

```
Class         Member                C-Value  M-Value 1  M-Value 2   Class  Member
Eeikehkt      Juxeizdiybnc            20.07     985.12    8816.17       0       0
Eeikehkt      Juxeizdiybnc            40.07     385.12    5816.17       0       1
Eeikehkt      Juxeizdiybnc            60.07     485.12    2816.17       0       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       0       4
Iamtppjo      Duxacewxhh              61.79     385.93    2477.32       1       0
Iamtppjo      Duxacewxhh              41.79     385.93    2477.32       1       1
Iamtppjo      Duxacewxhh              91.79     385.93    2477.32       1       2
Iamtppjo      Duxacewxhh              21.79     385.93    2477.32       1       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       1       4
Harbegghs     Javqaqetlmf             66.53     103.14    6106.43       2       0
Harbegghs     Javqaqetlmf             56.53     103.14    7106.43       2       1
Harbegghs     Javqaqetlmf             46.53     103.14    8106.43       2       2
Harbegghs     Javqaqetlmf             36.53     103.14    9106.43       2       3
Harbegghs     Javqaqetlmf             26.53     103.14    1106.43       2       4
Zumnyqmiq     Luoyjcvvdtwh            36.89     435.08    5337.35       3       0
Zumnyqmiq     Luoyjcvvdtwh            56.89     435.08    5337.35       3       1
Zumnyqmiq     Luoyjcvvdtwh            76.89     435.08    5337.35       3       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       3       4
Zagahwfn      Hanhmrcdgryn            84.58     598.20    8854.05       4       0
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       4       1
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       4       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       4       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       4       4
Keivsvmcb     Maaqjraizoaz            36.60     316.95    4320.89       5       0
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5       1
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       5       4
Hoawiopqby    Puqezsvrscs             44.77     131.01    4315.89       6       0
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       1
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       6       4
Zifummkfm     Uitgzpnziz              94.29     342.45    2152.53       7       0
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       1
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       7       4
Fikwzidv      Iamjbgihhrb             59.63     915.11    9885.05       8       0
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       8       1
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       8       2
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       8       3
                                       0.00       0.00       0.00       8       4
```

If that's not what you're expecting, show some sample data and the desired output.

---

#### Continued debugging

The code above omits printing the last class processed, as discussed in the commentary. I've done some more variable renaming and avoided the initialization loops.  The use of `class_idx` (for current class index in array) and `num_classes` for number of classes should make the code easier to understand.  I also added a `class_size` array to keep a record of how many entries are present in each class.  The code also strips carriage returns from the end of the line, carefully.  It still skips empty data lines (ones with only a line ending).  I removed the two 'unused' structure members, `calc_output1` and `calc_output2`, since they are not relevant to this code.  I've made the debugging output conditional on the value of the variable `debug`, which is set to `0` in this code.  You could arrange to be able to set it to one by a command line argument or an environment variable.

I've also cleaned up the use of `strncpy()` in the `readFile()` function.  It was not doing what you wanted — it was providing no overflow protection because you specified that the length available was the length of the source string, not the length of the target string. In fact, it was also ensuring that `strncpy()` was not null terminating the copied string, leaving it blank padded (because of the initialization loops — which were removed in this revision) — something that's quite hard to spot given the tabular output. The `safer_copy()` function encapsulates the operation correctly, I believe.  It takes the view that overlong names are fatal errors; you can choose to truncate instead if you prefer.  I'd then use `memmove()` (or perhaps `memcpy()`) to copy the data and would manually null-terminate the target string).  As with most things, there's more than one way to do it (the Perl motto — aka TMTOWTDI) and you need to choose for yourself which is best for your requirements.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct csv
{
    char class_name[12];
    char member[18];
    double class_value;
    double member_value1;
    double member_value2;
};

static int debug = 0;

static
void safer_copy(const char *p, char *dst, size_t dst_size, const char *tag)
{
    if (strlen(p) >= dst_size)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Overlong %s [%s] (%zu vs %zu maximum)\n",
                tag, p, strlen(p), dst_size - 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(dst, p);
}

static
int readFile(char *csvFile, struct csv *csv_rec, size_t max_records)
{
    FILE *dataFile = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    char fileLine[255] = {0};

    dataFile = fopen(csvFile, "r");
    if (dataFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", csvFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (idx = 0; fgets(fileLine, sizeof(fileLine), dataFile) != NULL; idx++)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(fileLine);
        if (len == 0)                   // Should never occur
            continue;
        assert(fileLine[len - 1] == '\n');
        fileLine[--len] = '\0';
        if (len == 0)                   // Could occur for empty line
            continue;
        if (fileLine[len - 1] == '\r')  // Detect CRLF line endings too
            fileLine[--len] = '\0';
        if (len == 0)                   // Could occur for empty line
            continue;
        if (idx >= max_records)
            break;
        if (debug) printf("[[%s]]\n", fileLine);
        char *data = fileLine;
        char *p;
        for (size_t fldidx = 0; (p = strtok(data, ",")) != NULL; data = NULL, fldidx++)
        {
            switch (fldidx)
            {
            case 0:
                safer_copy(p, csv_rec[idx].class_name,
                           sizeof(csv_rec[idx].class_name), "class name");
                break;
            case 1:
                safer_copy(p, csv_rec[idx].member,
                           sizeof(csv_rec[idx].member), "member");
                break;
            case 2:
                csv_rec[idx].class_value = atof(p);
                break;
            case 3:
                csv_rec[idx].member_value1 = atof(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                csv_rec[idx].member_value2 = atof(p);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(dataFile);
    return idx;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int max_members = 25;
    int max_classes = 25;
    int max_records = 75;
    struct csv csv_data[max_members][max_classes];
    struct csv csv_read[max_records];
    int class_size[max_members];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s datafile.csv\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int num_records = readFile(argv[1], csv_read, max_records);
    if (num_records == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: empty data file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    int member_idx = 0;
    int class_idx = 0;
    int max_group = 0;

    csv_data[class_idx][member_idx] = csv_read[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < num_records; i++)
    {
        assert(member_idx < max_members && class_idx < max_classes);
        if (strcmp(csv_read[i].class_name, csv_read[i - 1].class_name) == 0)
            member_idx++;
        else
        {
            if (member_idx > max_group)
                max_group = member_idx;
            class_size[class_idx++] = member_idx + 1;
            member_idx = 0;
        }
        csv_data[class_idx][member_idx] = csv_read[i];
        if (debug)
            printf("[%d,%d] - %s\n", class_idx, member_idx, csv_read[i].class_name);
    }
    class_size[class_idx] = member_idx + 1;
    int num_classes = class_idx + 1;
    if (debug)
        printf("Classes = %d, max members = %d\n", num_classes, max_group);

    printf("%-12s  %-18s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %6s  %6s\n",
           "Class", "Member", "C-Value", "M-Value 1", "M-Value 2", "Class", "Member");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_classes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < class_size[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("%-12s  %-18s  %9.2f  %9.2f  %9.2f  %6d  %6d\n",
                   csv_data[i][j].class_name, csv_data[i][j].member,
                   csv_data[i][j].class_value, csv_data[i][j].member_value1,
                   csv_data[i][j].member_value2, i, j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One thing this shows is that you can almost always polish a program.  I'd not claim this is perfect by any stretch of my imagination.  For example, if a line is missing some fields, you get arbitrary garbage stored in the records; the code doesn't trim leading or trailing blanks from the name fields.

On the sample data from the question, the output is:

```
Class         Member                C-Value  M-Value 1  M-Value 2   Class  Member
RTI-31        nma-10-325              -9.19      -1.70     -17.76       0       0
RTI-31        nma-04-176              -9.19      -0.71     -17.30       0       1
RTI-31        nma-04-176r             -9.19      -1.78     -18.89       0       2
RTI-31        md2-02-280              -9.19      -6.72     -17.31       0       3
RTI-31        nma-10-346              -9.19     -11.25     -15.85       0       4
RTI-31        nma-04-263              -9.19     -11.71     -15.04       0       5
RTI-31        nma-08-195              -9.19      -4.28     -14.86       0       6
RTI-31        nma-04-009              -9.19      -9.96     -15.38       0       7
RTI-32        nma-10-088              -8.12       3.40     -13.82       1       0
RTI-32        nma-04-394              -8.12       5.88     -19.00       1       1
RTI-32        nma-08-230              -8.12       0.41     -17.51       1       2
RTI-32        md2-01-186              -8.12       2.30     -18.42       1       3
RTI-32        md2-02-029              -8.12      -0.85     -19.88       1       4
RTI-32        md2-03-113              -8.12      -2.13     -17.89       1       5
RTI-32        md2-03-408              -8.12      -2.38     -19.10       1       6
RTI-32        nma-08-230r             -8.12      -3.52     -15.81       1       7
RTI-32        md2-02-440              -8.12      -1.19     -19.54       1       8
RTI-32        nma-10-450              -8.12      -8.15     -16.32       1       9
RTI-55        nma-10-001             -10.82      -5.53     -21.43       2       0
RTI-55        mod-15-206             -10.82      -7.89     -15.78       2       1
RTI-55        mod-15-315             -10.82      -8.86     -14.75       2       2
RTI-55        md2-02-326             -10.82      -5.71     -17.27       2       3
RTI-55        md2-02-385-2ns         -10.82      -4.12     -19.36       2       4
RTI-55        md2-02-385             -10.82      -4.95     -18.98       2       5
RTI-55        mod-20-399             -10.82     -10.22     -16.33       2       6
RTI-55        nma-04-221             -10.82     -10.72     -16.92       2       7
RTI-55        nma-10-386             -10.82      -1.86     -16.20       2       8
RTI-83        nma-10-442              -8.78      -2.05     -15.32       3       0
RTI-83        nma-07-088              -8.78      -0.54     -15.73       3       1
RTI-83        md2-02-373              -8.78      -1.91     -16.11       3       2
RTI-83        nma-08-131              -8.78       0.31     -19.40       3       3
RTI-83        nma-08-496              -8.78       1.26     -19.86       3       4
RTI-83        nma-08-496r             -8.78      -3.21     -19.78       3       5
RTI-83        nma-10-083              -8.78      -1.39     -16.46       3       6
RTI-112       nma-04-356             -10.02      -7.70     -18.75       4       0
RTI-112       nma-12-269             -10.02      -2.04     -17.43       4       1
RTI-112       md2-02-251             -10.02      -4.16     -18.11       4       2
RTI-112       md2-03-020             -10.02      -5.53     -18.66       4       3
RTI-112       md2-03-112             -10.02      -4.62     -17.90       4       4
RTI-112       md2-05-001r            -10.02      10.61     -18.17       4       5
RTI-112       md2-02-424             -10.02      -6.75     -14.45       4       6
RTI-112       md2-04-136             -10.02      -1.42     -17.53       4       7
RTI-112       md2-04-432             -10.02       5.71     -19.63       4       8
RTI-112       nma-12-269r            -10.02       6.29     -21.19       4       9
RTI-112       md2-02-366             -10.02      -7.40     -15.28       4      10
RTI-112       nma-10-060             -10.02       0.20     -16.08       4      11
RTI-112       nma-10-009             -10.02      -8.50     -15.47       4      12
RTI-121       nma-04-080              -8.23     -13.27     -19.92       5       0
RTI-121       md2-02-121              -8.23      -6.91     -21.20       5       1
RTI-121       md2-01-352              -8.23      -3.91     -20.06       5       2
RTI-121       md2-02-008              -8.23      -7.47     -20.42       5       3
RTI-121       md2-03-176              -8.23     -10.52     -20.31       5       4
RTI-121       md2-03-414              -8.23      -8.16     -21.51       5       5
RTI-121       md2-02-161              -8.23     -10.90     -18.38       5       6
RTI-121       md2-02-385              -8.23       0.52     -16.90       5       7
RTI-121       nma-09-401              -8.23      -9.56     -18.10       5       8
RTI-121       nma-10-395              -8.23      -2.74     -17.79       5       9
RTI-311       nma-10-120              -9.19     -13.43     -14.87       6       0
RTI-311       md2-02-009              -9.19      -6.89     -15.64       6       1
RTI-311       mod-22-300              -9.19     -12.77     -16.03       6       2
CPT           mod-08-107              -7.82       4.24     -19.76       7       0
CPT           md2-02-359              -7.82      -3.74     -16.07       7       1
CPT           mod-22-290              -7.82       6.62     -16.84       7       2
CPT           nma-10-155              -7.82      -1.79     -13.30       7       3
CPT           nma-10-405              -7.82      -2.60     -15.99       7       4
CFT           mod-08-220              -8.45      -3.41     -18.91       8       0
CFT           md2-02-111              -8.45      -6.57     -14.84       8       1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you! As I mentioned, I'm still learning, and this problem was an excellent learning opportunity. My apologies for the typos in the code; I had a more specific bit of code but tried to make it more general with the hopes that it would be more useful to Stack Overflow users.

Comment: Hi Jonathan; last night when I ran this with your sample csv it worked fine - and since mine is formatted the same way, I thought it would also work the same. However, when I ran the code using some of my own sample data, there seemed to be errors. For example, the following data file (see original pose above for my data file and output). I used C99, as the compiler demanded - could it be a related problem?

Comment: Does your data have `CRLF` line endings (was it transferred via a Windows machine at some point)?  If so, that accounts for the odd positioning of the `]]` markers in the diagnostic output — the CR moved the print position back to the start of the line before the `]]` was added.  I'm looking into the absence of the CFT records.

Comment: @RoryClague: If you observe more carefully than I did last night, running my program on my sample data skips the last entry (it prints the entry for `Fikwzidv Iamjbgihhrb` but not the one for `Yutihgddt Augpvalibavo`).  The last loop needs to be `for (int i = 0; i <= classes; i++)` with `<=` rather than `<`.  Or `classes` needs to be incremented once more in the processing loop so that the `<` condition remains correct.

Comment: Ah, yes - this particular csv was transferred from Windows. Thank you for that insight.

Comment: Yes - easy fix, that. The data structure is being loaded - it just wasn't printing quite as expected. I hoped that was the case. Thank you again for all of your help, Jonathan.